# Having difficulty obtaining subset in R

Tags: r, select, subset

I'm trying to subset a data set with the following requirements:

1. `ethnicity` is `xyz`
2. `education` is Bachelor's Degree and above, i.e. `Bachelor's Degree` or `Graduate Degree`
3. I then want to look at the income bracket of those who meet the above requirements. A bracket would be something like `$30,000 - $39,999`, or `$100,000 - $124,999`.
4. Finally, as my final output, I want to see the subset obtained from the third item (above) with the column of whether or not those individuals are religious. In the data set, that corresponds to `religious` and `not religious`.

So it would look something like this

```
   income               religious
$30,000 - $39,999      not religious
$50,000 - $59,999         religious
  ....                    ....
  ....                    ....
```

*Keeping mind those listed satisfy requirements 1 and 2.*

Please bear in mind that I am new to programming. I've tried to figure this out for a very long time and have dug through many posts. I can't seem to get anything to work. How do I fix this?  Someone please help.

---

So as to not take away from the clarity of the post, I'll post what I've tried below (but feel free to ignore it as it's probably rubbish).

I have tried many variations of the following just to get to step 3, but have failed miserably, and am about to bash my head with the keyboard:

```
df$income[which(df$ethnicity == "xyz" & df$education %in% c("Bachelor's Degree", "Graduate Degree"), ]
```

I've also tried:

```
race <- df$ethnicity == "xyz"
ba_ma_phd <- df$education %in% c("Graduate Degree", "Bachelor's Degree")
income_sub <- df$income[ba_ma_phd & race]
```

I *believe* `income_sub` gets me up to step 3, but I have no idea how to get it to step 4.

Comment: You are almost there; as income is a vector rather than a dataframe, you do not need the trailing comma. ie you can use `df$income[which(df$ethnicity == "xyz" & df$education %in% c("Bachelor's Degree", "Graduate Degree") ]`. Note though if ethnicity or eduction are missing, you may want to include the non-missing variables in your subset statement. (if you want to create a subsetted data, then do not include `df$income` at the start, just use `df` and keep the comma this time, ... so `sub_df <- df[which(df$ethnicity == "xyz" & df$education %in% c("Bachelor's Degree", "Graduate Degree"), ]`

Comment: @user20650 then how do I get the corresponding column `religious`?

Comment: Im a bit unclear in what you want... just this perhaps `table(sub_df$income, sub_df$religious)` or do you want the full columns `sub_df[c("income", "religious")]`

Comment: @user20650 no, the corresponding rows in religious should display only the "religious-ness" of the individuals subsetted from the income bracket. Aren't the two options that you listed the same thing?

Comment: No theyre not the same... the first one produces a table giving the counts of observations for each income that are religious or not. The second just selects the income and religious columns from the subsetted data, and does not summarise them,

Comment: @user20650 You should post your comments as an answer

Comment: sure they are getting a bit long ... have we reached the answer? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change my comment as it was a bit too long.

First your code, you are almost there; as income is a vector rather than a dataframe, you do not need the trailing comma. 
ie you can use

```
df$income[which(df$ethnicity == "xyz" & 
         df$education %in% c("Bachelor's Degree", "Graduate Degree") ] 
 # note no comma after the closing bracket
```

If you want to create a subsetted data, then do not include `df$income` at the start, just use `df` and keep the comma this time. This will subset your data, but keep all columns

```
sub_df <- df[which(df$ethnicity == "xyz" &
       df$education %in% c("Bachelor's Degree", "Graduate Degree"), ]
```

To then look at the `income` levels for the subsetted data, you can use `table`

```
table(sub_df$income)
```

You can again use `table` to examine the counts of observations for each `income` by `religious` status.

```
table(sub_df$income, sub_df$religious)
```

If you just want to select the `income` and `religious` columns you can also do this using `[`

```
sub_df[c("religious", "income")]
```

Comment: you're very welcome, the [R tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info) has some really useful links

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(ethnicity == "xyz" & 
         education %in% c("Bachelor's Degree", "Graduate Degree")) %>%
  group_by(religious) %>%
  summarize(lower_bound = min(income),
            upper_bound = max(income) )
```